# Magento2 - Product as packs

Tags: magento2

My store sell products as individual and as packs, but I only want to create one product.
So I was thinking about using the customization Options, but the problem is when the user selects an option, the options price gets added to the original price.

Is there any way to replace the actual price with the options price.

Answer (score 0):

While u adding simple products to pack you can add custom price to those simple products inside the pack.

Otherwise, you can choose price for pack products simply.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but can you explain more.

Comment: After you selected Bundled items there is an option to add price for bundled items. Otherwise, simply you can enter the price in the top price box.